# Navigation item spacing

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have been working on my navigation menu offline, looked fine locally but when I uploaded it online half the changes didn't take effect on Chrome, and on Firefox it was still giving me a different design than what I am trying to create. Just wondered what I may be doing wrong here. I've provided a link to the design, and a live url for the current progress.

A couple of things I am trying to fix are:

1 - Just trying to get the overal design correct
2 - There is blank space between each menu item, need that removed too.

Design: http://cl.ly/RSwr

URL: http://www.jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish

HTML

```
<div id="navigation"> 
                        <ul>
                            <li class="home-nav-bg"><a href="#"></a>
                            <li class="how-nav-bg"><a href="#">Example Us</a>
                            <li class="boxes-nav-bg"><a href="#">Example</a>
                            <li class="recipes-nav-bg"><a href="#">Example</a>
                            <li class="food-nav-bg"><a href="#">Example</a>
                            <li class="kitchen-nav-bg"><a href="#">Example</a>
                            <li class="nav-end-bg"><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
    #navigation {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}

#navigation ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}

#navigation li {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    text-align: right;
}

#navigation li a {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

.home-nav-bg {
    background-image: url('../img/home-nav-bg.png');
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.how-nav-bg {
    background-color: #bf0e51;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.boxes-nav-bg {
    background-color: #bf0e51;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.recipes-nav-bg {
    background-color: #bf0e51;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.food-nav-bg {
    background-color: #bf0e51;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.kitchen-nav-bg {
    background-color: #bf0e51;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.nav-end-bg {
    background-image: url('../img/nav-end-bg.png');
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Ok I got rid of the list-item spacing issues, thanks.

Comment: Issue i'm having now is it's showing completely different on chrome vs firefox. Firefox is fine, chrome is not showing any of the padding on each list-item.

Comment: @mcvities, I've noticed you've been obscuring the content on all your questions. Please don't do this! While the issue may have been resolved for you, others will still benefit from the Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with inline and inline-block elements is the browser pads the whitespace between because these elements are generally text related, for example words.

You can set these to display block and float them or use one of the methods outlined in this post. I generally prefer to use inline-block.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.

Issue i'm having now is it's showing completely different on chrome vs firefox. Firefox is fine, chrome is not showing any of the padding on each list-item

Comment: Are your changes live on your site?

Comment: Yeah. If you have a look right now it's still a little different on chrome and firefox. Will stop for a few minutes after this post to allow people to look.

Comment: If his answer helped you with your original issue, please upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
#navigation li{
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
 text-align: right;
 float: left;
 height: 48px;
 line-height: 48px;
}
.nav-end-bg{
background-image: url('../img/nav-end-bg.png');
width: 111px;
height: 75px !important;
}
```

that works fine.